# Test schema with data to run queries on it

Tags: sql-server

Does SQL Server have some test schema with data like customers, orders, etc to run queries on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AdventureWorks sample databases](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2000 - [NorthWind and Pubs databases](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23654)

For SQL Server from 2005 -  [AdventureWorks database](http://sqlserversamples.codeplex.com/)